# Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу при работе с динамическим массивом

Tags: c, массивы

Процедура получает на вход массив целых чисел и число элементов в нем и дожлна с использованием динамической памяти перегруппировать его таким образом, чтобы в начале стояли четные элементы, а затем нечетные

```
void oddeven_dyn(int* A, int n)
{
 int B_left = 0;
 int B_right = n;
 int* B = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
 for (int i = 0; i < n; n++)
 {
     if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
         B[B_left++] = A[i];// на этой строке возникает ошибка
     else
         B[B_right--] = A[i];
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     A[i] = B[i];
 free(B);
}
```

Comment: Непонятно. Вот если на `B[B_right--] = A[i];` — тогда другое... Но зачем вам вообще еще один массив?...

Comment: Если вам не нужно сохранять относительный порядок элементов, то посмотрите, как работает процедура разделения в quicksort и примените подобный подход. Дополнительный массив не понадобится

Comment: По задумке четные числа должны записываться с левого конца массива, а нечетные с правого. В задании требуется, чтобы использовалась динамическая память

Comment: B_right = n-1..

Comment: Посмотрите на https://ideone.com/arov73

Comment: c B_right = n-1 все работает, спасибо)

Comment: Значит, ошибка все же не на той строке, где вы указали.

Comment: бесконечный цикл `for (int i = 0; i < n; n++)` исправьте  на правильный